# UIActionSheet should be called from the popover but shown from the bottom of the main screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uiactionsheet

I have a `UIActionSheet` called from the button which is displayed in popover in the cell. When I use iPhone - the `UIActionSheet` is called from the bottom of the screen, but now I need to transform the UI for iPad - so now the VC is shown in popover and `UIActionSheet` is displayed in popover too. Is it possible to present the `UIActionSheet` from the bottom of the iPad screen too while the sender is displayed in popover?

The code for presenting UIActionSheet is:

```
- (void) showActionSheet
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Отмена"
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Наличие несуществующего объекта", @"Некорректность значений атрибутов", nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

used [actionSheet showFromRect: popover.frame inView: self.view animated: YES];

it may work for you